# jQuery add numbered class recursively to blocks of divs

Tags: jquery, html, class, addition

I'm dinamically wrapping a fixed number of divs from an array (e.g. 4 in each group).
The number of `.item` div's returned from the array is unknown...
I need to recursively add the same class to those groups of divs wrapped toghether:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<!-- more divs follow... -->
<div class="wrapper">
   ...
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   ...
</div>
```

and this is tghe final result:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item div-01"></div>
  <div class="item div-02"></div>
  <div class="item div-03"></div>
  <div class="item div-04"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item div-01"></div>
  <div class="item div-02"></div>
  <div class="item div-03"></div>
  <div class="item div-04"></div>
</div>
<!-- more divs follow... -->
<div class="wrapper">
   ...
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   ...
</div>
```

the code I'm using to wrap the divs:

```
var divs = $(".item");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
    divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need this? My advice would be to use a single event handler using the `$('.item')` selector, and then `eq()` to find the position of the current element in the set.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - I need the `.wrapper` class to make a slideshow,  and i need to enumerate each `.item` div for animation purpose. Each `.item` in each slide has the same animation, (dimensions, position...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// For each `.wrapper`
$('.wrapper').each(function() {

    // Get all the `.item` inside this `.wrapper`
    $(this).find('.item').each(function () {
        var class = ($(this).index()) > 9 ? $(this).index() : 0 + $(this).index();
        $(this).addClass('div-' + class);
        // Add class using the `index()` of this element
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rv2jc04c/)

Comment: This version is not working for me, the one that works (and i accepted) is the one in your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rv2jc04c/)

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    $.each($(this).children('.item'), function(k,v) { // k = index, v = value
        $(this).addClass('div-' + (k < 9 ? '0' : '') + (k+1));
    });
});
```

Loop over the items using the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and add the class using the index.

Comment: No need for the `if`: `$(this).addClass('div-' + ('0' + (k + 1)).substring(-2));`

Comment: Also good I just added another shorter version to combine them together

Comment: Sorry if my post is not clear, but the number of  `.wrapper` could be more than 2 and the number of `.item` cold be more than 8...

Comment: @uomopalese This is working, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/mqtbtxkv/)

Comment: @Mivaweb - it works now, you'ree right, but your first version was breaking my code.. I'm not a jQuery guru, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my old-school 2-D loop solution. Looping over class `wrapper` and then on `item`.

```
var i = 0;
$('.wrapper').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.item').each(function () {
       i++;
       $(this).addClass("item-"+i);
    });
    i = 0;
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0meLbsyb/1/)**