# Why I can't create an ID for my new select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create new `select` element, append it to a div and then to fill it with some data. The problem is that I need an unique ID for every drop down.

I'm trying the following code:

```
var dropDowns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                dropDowns[i] = $('<select id=\"data_\"' + i + '>').appendTo('.dropDowns');
                for (var b = 0; b < data['data_' + data.results[i]].length; b++) {
                    dropDowns[i].append($("<option>").attr('value', data['data_' + data.results[i]][b].id).text(data['data_' + data.results[i]][b].description));
                }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to assign `'data_' + i`, but my element looks like:

```
<select id="data_" 0="">
```

But it should look like:

```
<select id="data_0">
```

I know that I'm missing something really small and basic, but I really can't spot it, as a js newbie.

Can you give me a push?

Comment: Try removing the `double quotes` around `data_`. Or try **[this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31116533/4365626)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting the " that ends the attribute value *before* the incrementing variable instead of after it.

```
'<select id=\"data_\"' + i + '>'
```

should be

```
'<select id=\"data_' + i + '\">'
```

---

That said, dynamically generated IDs are generally a bad idea. You'd almost certainly be better off just keeping a reference to the element in a JS array or finding it based on its position in the DOM (e.g. `myForm.querySelectorAll('select')[i]`).